# Compiles but crashes every time #class template c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I need your help. I don't understand why but, when I compile my program, it crashes. If I remove the

```
bool c = tabInt==TabInt2;
```

in my main, it doesn't crash. Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem?

`MonTableau.h`

```
template <class Type> class MonTableau
{

    private:
    int debut;
    int fin;
    int taille;
    Type * adr;

    public:
        MonTableau (int, int);
        MonTableau (int);
        ~MonTableau();
        Type & operator [] (int);           
        bool operator == (MonTableau) const;
        bool  operator != (MonTableau) const;
};
```

`MonTableau.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MonTableau.h"
using namespace std;



template<class Type> 
MonTableau<Type> :: MonTableau (int d, int f)
    {
        if(f>d)
        {
            debut=d;  fin=f ; taille= f-d; adr= new Type [taille];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Taille non valide" << endl;
        }
    }

template<class Type> 
MonTableau<Type>::      MonTableau (int f)
    {
        if(f>0)
        {
            debut=0;  fin=taille=f ; adr= new Type [taille];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Taille non valide" << endl;
        }
    }

template<class Type> 
MonTableau<Type>::  ~MonTableau() {delete adr;}

template<class Type> 
    Type& MonTableau<Type>::  operator [] (int i)
    {
    return adr[i-debut];

    }


template<class Type>            
bool MonTableau<Type> :: operator == (MonTableau a) const
{

if(taille==a.taille)
{
    for(int k=0;k<taille;k++)
        {
            if( adr[k] != a.adr[k])  return false;
        }
         return true;
}
else return false;
}




template<class Type> 
bool MonTableau<Type>:: operator != (MonTableau a) const
{
if(taille==a.taille)
{
    for(int i=0;i<taille;i++)
        {
            if(adr[i]!=a.adr[i])  return true;
        }
         return false;
}
else return true;   
}





int main()
{
MonTableau<int> tabInt(5);
MonTableau<int> TabInt2(-2,3);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    TabInt2[i-2]=tabInt[i]=i;
}
bool c = tabInt==TabInt2;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with your wording. I bet your program compiles fine both ways, but it crashes when you run it. Then: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: _@JDoe_ [Notable read for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) as you're going to develop this further.

Comment: i tried to debug it, but when i press debug, my compilator crashes. What do you mean by ''be careful with your wording"?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: When you `new []` you must `delete []` (not just `delete`), or the program is undefined.

Comment: @user0042 Clarified my comment so you can understand it.

Comment: @molbdnilo I already wondered ;-). It's clear now.

Comment: @user0042 i've read it, but there are no exemple of overload operator on templates

Comment: @J.Doe Did you even read what I linked? How does it matter if the functions are operators or not? If you're gonna separate out the `main()` from your implementation `.cpp` file, you'll face linker errors. The template definitions should go to the header file, or a file that can be included to your template header file without scewing up your build system.

Comment: but my main is in my .cpp file. I think i don't understand your comment. let me read your link again

Comment: @J.Doe What I mean: It is very rare that a compiler crashes. It can happen, but really only in very rare circumstances. So, I think it is not the compiler that crashes, but your program. Also, when you debug it, I assume you did not set a breakpoint first, so your program is run and crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not following [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

You are making a shallow copy of the object when you call the `operator==` function. When that objects gets out of scope, you delete the memory. That memory is deleted again when the variables in `main` get out of scope. That causes undefined behavior. In your case, that causes the program to crash.

You can temporarily fix the problem by passing `const&` in the `operator==` and `operator!=` functions.

```
  bool operator == (MonTableau const&) const;
  bool  operator != (MonTableau const&) const;
```

The real fix is to follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: The rule of 3 became the rule of five in C++11

Answer (score 0):

This line is just wrong:

```
TabInt2[i-2]=tabInt[i]=i;
```

You initialize i to 0 but then modify the item at index -2.

Also, you don't initialize the following members, so their value is undefined:

```
int taille;
Type * adr;
```

Comment: I don't understand why it would be wrong since i've overload the [] operator. Also, my constructor initialise those 2 informations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (I suppose) is that your class doesn't have a copy constructor.

So, when you pass `MonTableau a` as **copy** to `operator!=()`, the copy `a` contain an `adr` with the same value of the calling `TabInt2`.

So the memory allocated (`new[]`) in `adr` of `TabInt2` is destroyed two times: the first one in `operator!=()`; the second time in `main()`.

This is a typical crash cause.

PS: as observed by molbdnilo, you have to use `delete []` for pointers allocated by `new []`. Also this problem can cause the crash.